# SVN activity log. Change of branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a possibility to get activity logs from a local copy of a SVN (Tortoise) repository? Struck on a situation when someone switched a branch on a local repository (some distant PC) and I want to find out 'who' (or at least 'when').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion does not log local operations. The repository only records operations which change the state of the repository. Switching branches on a working copy does not affect the repository at all, so I'm not sure what you think you're going to gain from this investigation.

If the user did something wrong on their working copy, just delete the working copy or revert the changes. Working copies are disposable. If they did something wrong and then committed the change to the repository, you can roll the change back to the correct state.

Comment: The part of "revert and etc" I agree on. It's more of a "entering to a shared working env(yea, i know how dumb this is) with uncommitted changes, starting a merge without knowing even how it was done, crashing it at the middle(I suppose it was done through task manager, because part of the project got binded to branch 2, while half remained on branch 1)" matter and leaving this mess unresolved. I know all of this is revertable and fixable, I just wanted to find out when it was done, and by time compare connections to that setup in order to find the person responsible.

Comment: The root of your issue is, as you already know, sharing working copies. WCs should never be shared because it introduces the chance for this sort of confusion and even worse, *a loss of accountability for changes.* Subversion assumes that only one person will be using a given WC and that that individual will generally do the right thing.

Comment: I know, but this is something I have no influence on(and I've learned my lesson on this). Just wanted to find out to whom I may pay my respect to in getting me to this point.

Comment: In the absence of evidence of who exactly did it, address everyone who has access to that shared location simultaneously, let them all know that the WC is hosed, and it's on them to sort it out. Maybe they'll learn from the experience that they're only hurting themselves.

Comment: Actually this is the point on which I got the idea that until I find the person myself, nobody will confess.